# TextWatcher - Replace last char of string

Tags: java, textwatcher

Everytime "q" is written as the last char of the edittext I attach TextWatcher on, that "q" to be replaced with "a". I use:

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(s.length() > 0 && s.toString().charAt(s.length()-1) == 'q')
        {
            current_string = s.toString();
            current_string = current_string.substring(0, (current_string.length()-1));
            et.setText(current_string);
            }
        }
```

But, as I test the code, when I type in "q" nothing happens. Some help? Thanks a lot

Comment: you forgot to append `a` after `substring()`

Comment: You should use `StringBuilder` , quick way would be `et.setText(current_string + "a");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont use the `afterTextChanged` that it is dangerous because it will be called recursively that you might get yourself into an infinite loop.

as the documentation is saying:

```
     It is legitimate to make further changes to s from this callback,
    but be careful not to get yourself into an infinite loop, because any 
   changes you make will cause this method to be called again recursively
```

use the `onTextChanged` instead.

In your problem

You forgot to add the character `a` into your string

```
public void onTextChanged (CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(s.length() > 0 && s.toString().charAt(s.length()-1) == 'q')
    {
        current_string = s.toString();
        current_string = current_string.substring(0, (current_string.length()-1));
        et.setText(current_string + "a"); //add the a after q is deleted
        }
    }
}
```